# Accessing class methods outside of a class with tkinters button command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm having an issue trying to call a class's method from a command on tkinters button. I have tried:

```
command = Alarm_clock.save_alarm()
command = self.save_alarm()
command = Alarm_clock.save_alarm(self.hour_count, self.min_count)
command = Alarm_clock.save_alarm(self)
```

I think I'm missing something obvious because I have managed to 'command' methods within the same class.

Here is a snippet of my code: It's for an alarm clock:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import vlc
import pygame
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3

class Alarm_clock():
    def __init__(self):
        alarm_list = []

    def save_alarm(self):
        print(init_alarm_gui.hour_count.get())
        print(init_alarm_gui.min_count.get())
        #get the hour and minute and append it to the alarm_list to be checked on real time

class init_alarm_gui():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.hour_count = 0
        self.min_count = 0

    def make_widgets(self, root):

        self.hour_count = tk.IntVar()

        self.min_count = tk.IntVar()

        self.time_label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.time_label.pack()

        self.Save_but = tk.Button(root, text = "Save Alarm", command=Alarm_clock.save_alarm)
        self.Save_but.pack()  

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = init_alarm_gui(root)
    gui.make_widgets(root)    
    root.mainloop()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
TyperError: save_alarm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Please use the general python tag if you don't know for certain that the issue is exclusive to 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create an instance of the class, and then call the method of the instance. This will automatically fill in the `self` parameter. This isn't unique to tkinter, it's just how python works.

```
alarm = Alarm_clock()
alarm.save_alarm()
```

Comment: Ok, so i have instantiated the class... But using the get() method to access the attribute of init_alarm_gui class says there is no attribute. Do i need to inherit the properties of init_alarm_gui to Alarm_clock?

Comment: @AlexWhite: no, the same rules apply. `init_alarm_gui` is a class. You need to be calling the method on an _instance_ of the class.